# ArrayList<...> is duplicated after update

Tags: android, arraylist

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I adapter receives data from the server and places them in the foliage. Then, when new data arrive, I try to update the adapter ... and as if all is well, but when it comes .. the new data, eg 2 messages, they are added to the adapter. But with the new data are added to all the other old dannye..Hotya logs on can see that the old data received I do not have a server. It turns out that it is not doing data.clear (). I carry ... data.clear (), my foliage becomes completely empty until the next request Handler.postDelayed () ;. Again request - full foliage and the new data ... 5 seconds passed and my clean sheet again ... and so constantly. How to overcome it?

My Adapter:

```
public class ChatMsgAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResponseMsgArray> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> data;


protected String LV_KEY = Auth.key;
protected int LV_USID = Integer.parseInt(Auth.id);
protected int GET_ID = Integer.parseInt(FriendActivity.get_id);


String LOG_TAG = "FriendLOG";

public ChatMsgAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> values) {
    super(context,R.layout.activity_friend_msg, values);

    this.data = values;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View v;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    if(type == LV_USID) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friend_msg_adapter, null);

        TextView user_id_msg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_msg);
        TextView user_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        TextView user_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);

        user_text.setText(data.get(position).getMsg());
        user_date.setText(data.get(position).getMsg_time());
        user_id_msg.setText(data.get(position).getMsg_id());

    } else if (type == GET_ID) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talker, null);

        TextView talker_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
        TextView talker_date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_time);
        talker_text.setText(data.get(position).getMsg());
        talker_date.setText(data.get(position).getMsg_time());

    } else {
        //Если нет например сообщений
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.msg_null, null);
    }

    return v;
}

public void setData(ArrayList<ResponseMsgArray> newData) {
    addAll(newData);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int newPosition = Integer.parseInt(data.get(position).getMsg_id_us());
    return newPosition;
}
}
```

Text translated with the help of an interpreter. Thank you for understanding.
Here in this post https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579311/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81/579403?noredirect=1#comment769066_579403 are all my current classes

Comment: You have to clear an arraylist first before adding items, if duplicate entries are your problem.

Comment: I'm doing this...writing `data.clear()`...now these are not repeated, but when the ListView is refreshed, the data disappear and then appear again.

Comment: Hm well I guess because he needs to reload all views and that takes a while. You could iterate over all new Data and only add it when data doesn't already contain it to prevent a full redrawing?

Comment: @cherry-wave, I have a query checks for the latest message, and if there are changes, it loads only the new data (the old data in the request no)

Comment: Please help me.